# Key Error in Python Script

Tags: python, dictionary, text-processing

Trying to run the following code I get a Key Error ln 12:

```
import math
from collections import Counter

def retrieve():

    wordFrequency = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}}
    search = {'bit':1,'dog':3,'shoe':5}

    sizeFileVec = {}
    for word, innerDict in wordFrequency.iteritems():
        for fileNum, appearances in innerDict.iteritems():
            sizeFileVec[fileNum] += appearances ** 2
            for fileNum in sizeFileVec:
                sizeFileVec[fileNum] = math.sqrt(sizeFileVec[fileNum])

    results = []
    for word, occurrences in search.iteritems():
        file_relevancy = Counter()
        for fileNum, appear_in_file in wordFrequency.get(word, {}).iteritems():
            file_relevancy[fileNum] += (occurrences * appear_in_file) / sizeFileVec[fileNum]

        results = [fileNum for (fileNum, count) in file_relevancy.most_common()]

    return results

print retrieve()
```

The code I am having an error with is supposed to take the inner dictionary of wordFrequency and then sum the squares of the values of each file number then square root this (there are 4 files) i.e. for file 1 it is sqrt(3^2 + 0^2 + 3^2).

- Edit

results []

is supposed to return a list of the 4 files in order of most relevant based on the query. So in this example:

```
          bit     dog      shoe

File 1     3       3         0

File 2     4       0         0

File 3    19       4         0

File 4     0       5         0


Search     1       3         5
```

sim(1,S) = (3 * 1) + (3 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(3^2 + 3^2 + 0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.478

The scalar product of each term is taken, then this is divided by the product of the magnitudes of the file and search.

This is done between the other 3 files and the search and stored in a list.

The list is then returned in order most relevant to least.

- edit 2

sim(2,S) = (4 * 1) + (0 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(4^2 + 0^2 + 0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.169

sim(3,S) = (19 * 1) + (4 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(19^2 + 4^2 +0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.26987

sim(4,S) = (0 * 1) + (5 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(0^2 + 5^2 + 0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.507

Therefore [4,1,3,2] should be returned

Comment: I run your code, but got error on line 12. Do you really get it on line 18?

Comment: No sorry there's a discrepancy!

Answer (score 1):

```
   sizeFileVec = {}
   for word, innerDict in wordFrequency.iteritems():
       for fileNum, appearances in innerDict.iteritems():
           sizeFileVec[fileNum] += appearances ** 2
```

This is wrong because the key doesn't yet exist, so python wouldn't know what to increment to`appearance**2`

You could do something like,

```
   sizeFileVec = {}
   for word, innerDict in wordFrequency.iteritems():
       for fileNum, appearances in innerDict.iteritems():
           if not sizeFileVec.has_key(filenum):
               sizeFileVec[filenum] = 0 #your default value
           sizeFileVec[fileNum] += appearances ** 2
```

(or use `setdefault` builtin method for the same effect). You need to make the same changes in line 18 where you repeat the above mistake.

Comment: This is still inside the for fileNum, appearances... ?

Comment: Yes that is working now thank you. I like Python but it can be a bit tricky sometimes! You cannot see anything wrong with the results = [] part?

Comment: @DannyBoy yes, you are overwriting the results array for each iteration of the loop. The last word is `shoe` which does not exist in `wordfrequency` so you'll naturally get an empty list.

Comment: But there would be no difference in actual output, it will just take longer to run?

Comment: @DannyBoy there is a difference in actual output. Whatever values were computed for bit and dog would be lost, and only the value for "shoe" is put into the result. I can help you if you explain what want your result to be.

Comment: Okay cool. It is supposed to give me a list of the most relevant files based on the search. Each different word is a different dimension of a vector. I'll give an explanation underneath my original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65486/discussion-between-dannyboy-and-pad).

Comment: Instead of `not sizeFileVec.has_key(filenum)` it would be more clear/pythonic to simply say `filenum not in sizeFileVec`

Comment: I see, although this is just tidying up, I'd rather the code does what it is supposed to do first before making it clearer. Do you have any ideas as to fixing the second part with the dot products and such?